# Cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type list when creating a lag variable by id

Tags: r, data.table, closures, lag

I want to create a lag variable of `RD_expenses` by using this code I found on this platform:

```
library(data.table)
TandCtable[, RDexp_pre1:=c(NA, "RD_expenses"[-.N]), by=id]
```

However, when i run the code i get this error:

```
Error in as.vector(x, "list") : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'list'
```

It probably has to do something with the data types, but I can't figure out what.

I need the lag variable to add as a covariate to my fixed effects model:

```
m5a <- felm(ihs(RD_expenses) ~ merger_it_pre1 + merger_it + merger_it_post1 + merger_it_post2 + merger_it_post3 + factor(year),
       data = TandC,
       subset = RD_expenses > pcts[1] & RD_expenses < pcts[2])
```

Help is much much much appreciated!

Edit: sorry, here is the data table!

```
structure(list(company = c("ALLERGAN PUBLIC LIMITED COMPANY", 
"ALLERGAN PUBLIC LIMITED COMPANY", "ALLERGAN PUBLIC LIMITED COMPANY", 
"ALLERGAN PUBLIC LIMITED COMPANY", "ALLERGAN PUBLIC LIMITED COMPANY", 
"ALLERGAN PUBLIC LIMITED COMPANY", "ALLERGAN PUBLIC LIMITED COMPANY", 
"ALPINE ELECTRONICS, INC.", "ALPINE ELECTRONICS, INC.", "ALPINE ELECTRONICS, INC.", 
"ALPINE ELECTRONICS, INC.", "ALPINE ELECTRONICS, INC.", "ALPINE ELECTRONICS, INC.", 
"ALPS ALPINE CO.,LTD.", "ALPS ALPINE CO.,LTD.", "ALPS ALPINE CO.,LTD.", 
"ALPS ALPINE CO.,LTD.", "ALPS ALPINE CO.,LTD.", "ALPS ALPINE CO.,LTD.", 
"ANICURA STOCKHOLMS REGIONDJURSJUKHUS AB"), year = c(2013L, 2014L, 
2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 
2019L, 2020L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2020L, 2015L
), case_code = c("M.8193", "M.8193", "M.8193", "M.8193", "M.8193", 
"M.8193", "M.8193", "M.8833", "M.8833", "M.8833", "M.8833", "M.8833", 
"M.8833", "M.8833", "M.8833", "M.8833", "M.8833", "M.8833", "M.8833", 
"M.9019"), merger = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018), acquirer = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor"), country = c("IE", "IE", "IE", "IE", 
"IE", "IE", "IE", "JP", "JP", "JP", "JP", "JP", "JP", "JP", "JP", 
"JP", "JP", "JP", "JP", "SE"), industry_firm = c(2120, 2120, 
2120, 2120, 2120, 2120, 2120, 6420, 6420, 6420, 6420, 6420, 6420, 
2611, 2611, 2611, 2611, 2611, 2611, 7500), industry_firm_2 = c(21, 
21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 26, 26, 26, 26, 
26, 26, 75), industry_merger = c(4646, 4646, 4646, 4646, 4646, 
4646, 4646, 453, 453, 453, 453, 453, 453, 453, 453, 453, 453, 
453, 453, 1092), industry_merger_2 = c(46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 
46, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 10), simpl_proc = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), commitments = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), cross_border = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), duration = c(25, 
25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
29, 29, 149), employees = c(384, 432, 624, 334, 356, 338, 348, 
1122, 1110, 1492, 1317, NA, NA, 39588, 42053, 42289, 41840, 40443, 
NA, 285), profit_margin = c(-0.14684, -0.85298, -0.58792, -0.38872, 
-1.30312, -0.86866, -0.6363, -1.925, 0.567, 3.984, 4.01, NA, 
NA, 8.763, 6.572, 7.599, 4.838, 1.921, NA, 8.049), RD_expenses = c(8946.414554, 
9977.75638, 43326.90616, 48870.14658, 35022.10866, 39584.25952, 
32259.2173, 6303.95, 6812.46, 14993.39, 21925.5, NA, NA, 259971.9513, 
269457.2012, 227757.0765, 263893.2745, 316285.6753, NA, 7053.5
), sales = c(125844.3945, 111010.5704, 276862.329, 276455.8596, 
265833.4972, 275762.3064, 286432.2966, 1260609.732, 1217111.106, 
1094409.478, 2057945, NA, NA, 6036362.168, 6288047.037, 6560212.444, 
6831502.438, 6806267.552, NA, 27113.77546), period = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 1L), .Label = c("-3", "-2", "-1", "0", "1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
    merger_it = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0), merger_it_pre1 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), merger_it_post3 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    merger_it_post2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), merger_it_post1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), RD_intensity = c(7.10910850621956, 
    8.98811378416267, 15.6492601635234, 17.6773777378817, 13.1744528168514, 
    14.3544852219875, 11.2624231565094, 0.500071500320608, 0.559723756230354, 
    1.36999818636439, 1.06540748173542, NA, NA, 4.30676530109749, 
    4.28522877794115, 3.47179422075435, 3.86288780389073, 4.6469768178164, 
    NA, 26.0144516222235), age = c(36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 
    54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 19), industry = c(46, 
    46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 
    45, 45, 45, 10), treated = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1"), id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001e028101ef0>)
```

Comment: Perhaps easier to use [shift](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.0/topics/shift)

Comment: Please paste in the result of `dput(TandCtable[1:20, ])` to make your example reproducible.

Comment: Don't use quotes around the column name. `TandCtable[, RDexp_pre1 := c(NA, RD_expenses[-.N]), by=id]`

Comment: Thanks!! Do you know if this also works if you would like a lag of 2 instead of 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use quotes around the column name.

```
library(data.table)
TandCtable[, RDexp_pre1 := c(NA, RD_expenses[-.N]), by=id]
```

If you want lag of different offset length it is better to use `shift` as suggested by @Waldi instead of appending `NA`'s.

```
TandCtable[, RDexp_pre1 := shift(RD_expenses, 2), by=id]
```

Comment: Thank you! However, if i use TandCtable[, RDexp_pre1 := shift(RD_expenses, 2), by=id], i shift the values upwards instead of downwards..

Comment: Any ideas how i can push the values downwards instead of upwards?

Comment: Default type is lag in `?shift`, you can use `type = 'lead'` i.e `TandCtable[, RDexp_pre1 := shift(RD_expenses, 2, type = 'lead'), by=id]`

Comment: I get this error: Error in shift(RD_expenses, 2, type = lead) : unused argument (type = lead)

Comment: Have you loaded `library(data.table)` ? `TandCtable[, RDexp_pre1 := shift(RD_expenses, 2, type = 'lead'), by=id]` works for me.

Comment: Restart R and try again.